# Excel web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, excel, pivot

Can excel web services be used to create pivot grids from asp.net or silverlight? And if so can i execute custom mdx in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms496823.aspx

it looks like you can have pivot grids

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly pull the information stored in an Excel workbook using the public Web Service API and then used that as data source for your asp .net or silverlight control. This can totally be done in server-side or client-side depending on your needs.

Additionally you can also try to use the [Excel Webpart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973804%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in you are already running SharePoint.